# GDAL/rasterio multiple windowed reads in one I/O call

Tags: python, gdal, rasterio, cloud-optimized-geotiff

I have a cloud optimized geotiff that I need to read multiple small windows from. My current implementation opens the geotiff using rasterio and then performs the windowed reads iteratively. However, even though rasterio uses caching which can avoid unnecessary I/O calls, this may cause multiple I/O calls to the geotiff, either to S3 or the disk and I want to know if there is a way to read multiple windows using one I/O call.

This is how I currently call rasterio in order to obtain the images I want:

```
rasters = []
with rasterio.open(path) as f:
    for window in windows:
        rasters.append(f.read(1, window))
```

Comment: Only by reading the entire image into memory in a single call, which kind of defeats the purpose windowed reading.

Comment: As far as I know, reading a cloud optimized geotiffs utilizes HTTP GET range requests where one can request a range of bytes to be read from the geotiff. Reading further on range requests, I have seen that it is possible to send multiple ranges in one range requests, thus making it theoretically possible to read multiple windows in one request with current tools.